# What is the syntax for a comment in a client library js.txt file?

Tags: aem, client-library

What is the syntax for adding a comment to a client library **js.txt** or **css.txt** file?

It *appears* that a line prefaced with `#` works as a comment, and it *appears* that a line prefaced with `//` works as a comment.  But `/*  */` blocks cause exceptions when the library is built.  Since `#base=[root]` has [special meaning](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics/clientlibs.html#Creating%20Client%20Library%20Folders), it makes me wonder if `#` is *really* an appropriate way to add a comment or if it is meant for something else.  It makes me wonder if `//` is *really* valid to make a comment or if AEM just treats this as a relative path to a file that doesn't exist.

Anyone know the definitive answer on the appropriate syntax for a comment in the js.txt or css.txt file of a client library?

Comment: I'll place my bet on `#` being a valid comment line excluding `#base`. For the rest comment formats, it might be trying to resolve those paths. If you're getting `RepositoryException` for `/* */` blocks, that may make sense as per [Session.itemExists API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html#itemExists(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` is safe to use in comments in a clientlibs `js.txt` and `css.txt`. Adobe for example uses this for their Copyright disclaimer:

```
###############################################################################
# Copyright 2016 Adobe Systems Incorporated
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
###############################################################################

#base=./js
modals.js
```

See official *We Retail* demo content on GitHub: [We Retail Clientlib Example on www.github.com](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sample-we-retail/blob/master/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/weretail/clientlibs/authoring/js.txt)

Answer (score 0):

```
(hash) Import-Package: *
```

We have to uncomment these lines while importing or exporting our bundle. But keep the same in case of js.txt or css.txt:

```
(hash)base=js
```

So (`hash`) is the way to comment but sometimes it is not a comment.